# Confusion in Python "return" statement

Tags: python, return, kivy

Actually I used kivy.uix.videoplayer moule to play my video and and I made a function in which I wrote code for playing video,

```
def hi(self):
    return VideoPlayer(source='it.mp4', state='play')
```

The confusion is when I use `return` it plays the video very well but when I don't use "return" VideoPlayer() like below:

```
def hi(self):
    VideoPlayer(source='it.mp4', state='play')
```

Then only sound plays, video is not shown and error comes that is;

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture it.mp4
```

I am little bit confused here in using `return` (I always was)
so please clear me about `return` statement.

Comment: The object created by `VideoPlayer` is subject to garbage collection as soon as that call completes, because you haven't saved a reference to it. You could get the same behavior with the `return` statement, if you don't assign the return value of `hi` to any name.

Comment: @chepner Thankyou

Answer (score 5):

Python objects are automatically *deleted* when nothing is referencing them anymore. By not returning the object, you basically ensured that there is nothing referencing the `VideoPlayer` object, and the Python object is deleted when the function returns.

When you use `return`, presumably whatever *calls* the `hi()` method stored a reference to the returned `VideoPlayer()` instance, keeping it alive:

```
video_player = someinstance.hi()
```

Without the `return` `None` is returned instead. If you leave in the `return` statement, but call `someinstance.hi()` directly without storing the return value anywhere, you'd get the same behaviour; the `VideoPlayer()` object being deleted because there are no references to it.

Kivy is not *just* Python; the Python objects are just proxies for native datastructures and code. The sound handler got started with the `VideoPlayer()` being created, but was not cleaned up with the object being deleted almost immediately.

Comment: Thanx @MartijinPieters